# Bank transaction using c

Tags: c, data-structures

The data about bank transactions consists of a sequence of transactions: the information of each transaction has the following format:

```
<from_account> <to_account> <money> <time_point> <atm>
```

In which:

- `<from_account>`: the account from which money is transferred (which is a string of length from 6 to 20 )
- `<to_account>`: the account which receives money in the transaction (which is a string of length from 6 to 20)
- `<money>`: amount of money transferred in the transaction (which is an integer from 1 to 10000)
- `<time_point>`: the time point at which the transaction is performed, it is a string with format HH:MM:SS (hour: minute: second)
- `<atm>`: the code of the ATM where the transaction is taken (a string of length from 3 to 10)

Write a program that process the following queries:
?total_ money transaction_from : compute the total amount of money transferred from the account

Input (stdin)

The input consists of 2 blocks of information: the data block and the query block

The data block consists of lines:

- Each line contains the information about a transaction described above
- The data is terminated by a line containing `#`

The query block consists of lines:

- Each line is a query described above
- The query block is terminated by a line containing `#`

Output (stdout)
Print to stdout (in each line) the result of each query described above

Example

```
Input
T000010010 T000010020 1000 10:20:30 ATM1
T000010010 T000010030 2000 10:02:30 ATM2
T000010010 T000010040 1500 09:23:30 ATM1
T000010020 T000010030 3000 08:20:31 ATM1
T000010030 T000010010 4000 12:40:00 ATM2
T000010040 T000010010 2000 10:30:00 ATM1
T000010020 T000010040 3000 08:20:31 ATM1
T000010040 T000010030 2000 11:30:00 ATM1
T000010040 T000010030 1000 18:30:00 ATM1
#
?total_money_transaction_from T000010010
?total_money_transaction_from T000010030
#
Output
4500
4000
```

Here is my code, this passes 4/5 testcases. However, the last one has 1 million data lines and 1 million query lines, which cause my code to exceed time limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char fAccount[21];
    char tAccount[21];
    int money;
    char time[9];
    char atm[11];
} transaction;

int data_input(transaction d[])
{
    char trash[21];
    int index = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%s", trash);
        if (strcmp(trash, "#") == 0)
            break;
        scanf("%s", d[index].tAccount);
        scanf("%d", &d[index].money);
        scanf("%s", d[index].time);
        scanf("%s", d[index].atm);
        strcpy(d[index].fAccount, trash);
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
int queries_input(transaction q[])
{
    int index = 0;
    char trash[100];
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%s", trash);
        if (strcmp(trash, "#") == 0)
            break;
        scanf("%s", q[index].fAccount);
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
void total_money(transaction d[], transaction q[], int size_d, int size_q)
{
    int money;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_q; i++)
    {
        money = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size_d; j++)
            if (strcmp(q[i].fAccount, d[j].fAccount) == 0)
                money += d[j].money;
        printf("%d\n", money);
    }
}
int main()
{
    transaction *data = (transaction *)malloc(sizeof(transaction) * 1000000);
    transaction *queries = (transaction *)malloc(sizeof(transaction) * 1000000);
    int size_d = data_input(data);
    int size_q = queries_input(queries);
    total_money(data, queries, size_d, size_q);
    free(data);
    free(queries);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could make a hash table, indexed by account ID and containing a sum of all the transfers from that account.  You could populate the table in a single pass when reading the transactions, and access it when reading the queries.  There is no need to store the transactions or the queries.  The only storage you need is the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Walking the entire list of transactions searching for transactions on an account is extremely slow.  One simple approach is to build a binary search tree so that each node is a list of transactions from a single account.  Then, lookup is a simple binary search for the account followed by walking a single list.  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct transaction {
        char fAccount[21];
        char tAccount[21];
        int money;
        char time[9];
        char atm[11];
        struct transaction *next;
        struct transaction *c[2];
};

static void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
        void *v = malloc(s);
        if( v == NULL ){
                perror("malloc");
                exit(1);
        }
        return v;
}


/* Insert n into the binary tree rooted at *root.  (Recursive) */
static void
insert(struct transaction **root, struct transaction *n)
{
        struct transaction *r = *root;
        int cmp;
        if( r == NULL ){
                n->next = n->c[0] = n->c[1] = NULL;
                *root = n;
        } else if( (cmp = strcmp(n->fAccount, r->fAccount)) == 0 ){
                n->c[0] = r->c[0];
                n->c[1] = r->c[1];
                n->next = r;
                *root = n;
        } else {
                insert(&r->c[cmp > 0], n);
        }
}

static int
query(const char *account, struct transaction *r)
{
        if( r == NULL ){
                return 0;
        }
        int cmp = strcmp(account, r->fAccount);
        if( cmp == 0 ){
                int sum = 0;
                for( ; r != NULL; r = r->next ){
                        sum += r->money;
                }
                return sum;
        } else {
                return query(account, r->c[cmp > 0]);
        }
}
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct transaction *r = NULL;
        struct transaction *t = NULL;
        while( (t = xmalloc(sizeof *t))
                && 5 == scanf(
                        "%20s %20s %12d %8s %10s",
                        t->fAccount,
                        t->tAccount,
                        &t->money,
                        t->time,
                        t->atm
                )
        ) {
                insert(&r, t);
        }
        if( strcmp(t->fAccount, "#")
                || strcmp(t->tAccount, "?total_money_transac")
        ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        while( 1 == scanf("%*s %20s", t->fAccount) ){
                printf("%d\n", query(t->fAccount, r));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Note that an unbalanced BST is *not* the best way to solve this problem.  In the worst case scenario (eg,the input is already sorted and there are unique "from" accounts) walking the tree is just as bad as walking a list as in your original implementation.  But this should give the general idea of how to implement the search with a data structure other than a simple list.

Comment: Why not use a hash table?  Then it will run in linear time rather than O(n*log(n)) time.  I'm sure a hash table is what they're looking for in this problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes I completely agree.  An (unbalanced) BST is a terrible approach to this problem, but it is easy to implement and provides (hopefully) some insight for the naive reader.